# ionic/cordova plugin errors while installing

Tags: git, cordova, github, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and git. In my application i am trying to install plugins. But I am keep getting this error for all plugins

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\share>cordova plugin add
>   https://github.com/wymse e/cordova-imagePicker.git Fetching plugin
>   "https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git" via git clon e
>   Repository "https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git" checked
>   out to gi t ref "master".

what exactly is this error? I am getting same error for other plugins as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see error message the command telling you what is going behind this .. Cordova fetching the plugin from the url via GIT technology and cloning it to your directory what is the problem with that!!

Could you please paste all other output to see if there were any errors.

Also you could make sure that the plugin is installed by running

```
cordova plugin
```

which list all installed plugins and you should see

```
cordova-plugin-image-picker
```

as one of them

Comment: my bad..as i am new to git, i thought it was the error.Thanks for clarification

Comment: No problems , glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Answer is in error message only.

i.e you have given unwanted space in url.

use this one

https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git

I hope it will work.

Comment: no there were no unwanted spaces and the same error for other plugins like social sharing,camera etc..

Comment: that space came while copying the log in cmd

Comment: Ok no problem, try now without space